# SQL Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, outer-join

I have a table named 'Logs' with the following values :

```
CheckDate        CheckType        CheckTime
-------------------------------------------
2011-11-25       IN               14:40:00
2011-11-25       OUT              14:45:00
2011-11-25       IN               14:50:00
2011-11-25       OUT              14:55:00
2011-11-25       IN               15:00:00
2011-11-25       OUT              15:05:00
2011-11-25       IN               15:15:00
2011-11-25       OUT              15:20:00
2011-11-25       IN               15:25:00
2011-11-25       OUT              15:30:00
2011-11-25       OUT              15:40:00
2011-11-25       IN               15:45:00
```

I want to use the previous table to produce a result of:

```
CheckDate        CheckIn        CheckOut
-----------------------------------------
2011-11-25       14:40:00       14:45:00
2011-11-25       14:50:00       14:55:00
2011-11-25       15:00:00       15:05:00
2011-11-25       15:15:00       15:20:00
2011-11-25       15:25:00       15:30:00
2011-11-25       NULL           15:40:00
2011-11-25       15:45:00       NULL
```

So far I have come up with this result set :

```
CheckDate        CheckIn        CheckOut
-----------------------------------------
2011-11-25       14:40:00       14:45:00
2011-11-25       14:50:00       14:55:00
2011-11-25       15:00:00       15:05:00
2011-11-25       15:15:00       15:20:00
2011-11-25       15:25:00       15:30:00
2011-11-25       15:45:00       NULL
```

The problem is I cannot generate the log without CheckIns :

```
CheckDate        CheckIn        CheckOut
-----------------------------------------
2011-11-25       NULL           15:40:00
```

The sequence of CheckIn - CheckOut pairing and order is in increasing time value.

EDIT : This is my current query

```
SELECT Ins.CheckDate,
       Ins.CheckTime,
       Outs.CheckTime

  FROM (SELECT CheckDate,
               CheckTime
          FROM Logs
         WHERE CheckType = 'I') Ins 

  FULL OUTER JOIN

       (SELECT CheckDate,
               CheckTime
          FROM Logs
         WHERE CheckType = 'O') Outs

    ON Ins.CheckDate = Outs.CheckDate AND
       Ins.CheckTime < Outs.CheckTime
```

Comment: "So far I have come up with this result set": Can you share the SQL for that?

Comment: Can you post the query you have that gave you the result?

Comment: Is that the full extent of the logs table or is there some other key for each entry? Can you include the SQL that you used to generate your current result set?

Comment: I fixed a regression introduced by an update. It should now cover every possible scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
;WITH x AS (
   SELECT CheckDate, CheckType, CheckTime
         ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CheckDate, CheckTime) As rn
   FROM #t
)
SELECT CASE WHEN x.CheckType = 'IN' OR x.rn = 1 THEN x.CheckDate 
                                               ELSE y.CheckDate END AS CheckDate
      ,CASE WHEN x.CheckType = 'IN'  THEN x.CheckTime ELSE NULL END AS CheckIn
      ,CASE WHEN y.CheckType = 'OUT' THEN y.CheckTime
            WHEN x.CheckType = 'OUT' THEN x.CheckTime ELSE NULL END AS CheckOut
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN x AS y ON y.rn = x.rn + 1
WHERE  x.CheckType = 'IN'
OR     y.CheckType = 'OUT'
OR     x.rn = 1
```

It produces exactly the output requested and covers special cases where

- `OUT` is followed by another `OUT` (missing `IN`)
- `IN`  is followed by another `IN` (missing `OUT`)
- `IN`  is followed by nothing (last row).
- first row starts with `OUT`.

Try the [working demo on data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119208/).

Comment: nice solution. simple and efficient.

Comment: @JustinGrant: Thanks, but actually the first row was missing if it started with 'OUT'. Wasn't in the question, but for science! That is covered now, too.  The switch from `y.CheckType` to `x.CheckType` in the CASE statement for `CheckOut` is a special treat to keep is simple and efficient in this context. :)

Comment: Common table expression, I'm not familiar with this one. I always depend on derived or temporary tables which is I think is longer to execute. (Am I correct?) Now I'm planning to remake my queries using this kind of approach. Big thanks to you Erwin. :)

Comment: @TormentMarch: The major advantages of CTE: you can reuse a CTE multiple times on the same or different query levels and the code is more readable. Performance is otherwise similar to a subquery. And there are also recursive CTE, but that is another story ...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the optimizers doesn't support "FULL OUTER JOIN" of sql
So,
Query should be:

```
SELECT Ins.CheckDate,
       Ins.CheckTime,
       Outs.CheckTime

  FROM (SELECT CheckDate,
               CheckTime
          FROM Logs
         WHERE CheckType = 'I') Ins 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN

       (SELECT CheckDate,
               CheckTime
          FROM Logs
         WHERE CheckType = 'O') Outs

    ON Ins.CheckDate = Outs.CheckDate AND
       Ins.CheckTime < Outs.CheckTime

UNION

SELECT Ins.CheckDate,
       Ins.CheckTime,
       Outs.CheckTime

  FROM (SELECT CheckDate,
               CheckTime
          FROM Logs
         WHERE CheckType = 'I') Ins 

  RIGHT OUTER JOIN

       (SELECT CheckDate,
               CheckTime
          FROM Logs
         WHERE CheckType = 'O') Outs

    ON Ins.CheckDate = Outs.CheckDate AND
       Ins.CheckTime < Outs.CheckTime
```